# Can I declare logic on jQuery for the start and end of a scrolling event?

Tags: jquery, events, scroll

I would like to setup logic for when the user begins scrolling around the page and after the scrolling is finished, how can I accomplish this?

I want to avoid the below as it means my logic will be fired repeatedly unnecessarily

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    console.log("scrolling");
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try defining you're own [debounced events](http://unscriptable.com/index.php/2009/03/20/debouncing-javascript-methods/). A (very crude) implementation would look something like this:

```
var t, l = (new Date()).getTime();

$(window).scroll(function(){
    var now = (new Date()).getTime();

    if(now - l > 400){
        $(this).trigger('scrollStart');
        l = now;
    }

    clearTimeout(t);
    t = setTimeout(function(){
        $(window).trigger('scrollEnd');
    }, 300);
});
```

**See: http://www.jsfiddle.net/yijiang/fGmbe/ for a live demo**

Comment: +1, brilliant ! Here is a contribution for an improved version, http://www.jsfiddle.net/fGmbe/1/