# Is it possible invoke a function only when I start the scroll?

Tags: jquery, scroll

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I declare logic on jQuery for the start and end of a scrolling event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096429/can-i-declare-logic-on-jquery-for-the-start-and-end-of-a-scrolling-event)

Tried this :

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    console.log("ciao");
});
```

but the function is invoked during the scrolling. I want to print "ciao" only when I start scrolling. Than not. Well, after block the scroll, when I restart, print again "ciao", and so on.

Is it possible invoke a function only when I Start the scroll?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096429/can-i-declare-logic-on-jquery-for-the-start-and-end-of-a-scrolling-event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in function for jQuery which allows you to detect scroll start or stop events.

There are several plugins which will enable this functionality though, try [this one](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/special-scroll-events-for-jquery/).

You can then change your code to this:

```
$(window).on('scrollstart', function() {
    console.log("ciao");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(window).bind("scrollstart", function() {
console.log("ciao");
});
```

You must include `jquery.scroll.events.js` file at first. You can look for more [here](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-scroll-events/wiki/Reference) and [here](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/special-scroll-events-for-jquery/)