# Detecting the end (drop) of a Scrollbar Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, scrollbar

I need to detect when a user has stopped scrolling **only in the Scrollbar**.

There is this site: http://beoplay.com/Products/BeoplayA9, that is already doing what I need.

I need to readjust page position if user has scrolled (with the scroll bar) and left the scroll between two pages. Notice that in the example website the page position is only readjusted at the 'drop' of the scroll bar.

This question has been asked many times, but not this way, I've already seen [this plugin by James Padolsey](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/special-scroll-events-for-jquery/), but it doesn't work as the example website.

I have some code already in a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/promatik/7rkGV/ 
The handling of the mouse wheel is done, but now I can't figure out how to handle the scroll bar move to know when it was dropped.

Maybe there is a away to differentiate the event from a *wheel* scroll and a *scroll bar* scroll.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function (event) {
    console.log(event);
});
```

Does anyone know how to replicate the effect in the [example](http://beoplay.com/Products/BeoplayA9)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery scroll() detect when user stops scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144560/jquery-scroll-detect-when-user-stops-scrolling)

Comment: @Diodeus as you may see in the example I provided I need a solution of *drop* the **scrollbar**, not a timer as in the answer given in the question you pointed. Sorry but that question doesn't help me.

Comment: I think you may only be able to determine that some non-scroll event has fired, or the timer method.

See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352112/jquery-blur-event-on-div-scrolbar

Comment: @Diodeus, all I see in every SO answer is the timer method, but if you take a look at the example I provided: http://beoplay.com/Products/BeoplayA9. It doesn't use the timer, because the trigger (that readjust the page position) only occurs when you **drop** the scrollbar. There must be a way to do that ...