# how to stop jquery .scroll triggering event too many times

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

Im making an animation using spritely.net It gives you a function to start the animation and a function to stop it.

I want the animation to start when someone starts scrolling down the page, and stop when they stop scrolling.

I am able to do this but the problem is .scroll triggers the animation start many times a second which makes the animation go crazy. You can see if you scroll down the page here:

http://jsfiddle.net/atyM6/

The animation when allowed to run properly should look more like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/wx7qb/1/

I've tried this plugin

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

and also this 
http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/#throttle

but haven't been able to get my jquery ready into a nice function that I can pass to it, and make the animation work. Also I've seen that other people have managed curtail .scroll() without using these plugins, but I have not been able to adapt their code to suit my purpose.

This is my jquery which starts and stops the animation - my sensing when user is scrolling.

```
 $(window).scroll( function() {
 $('#bird')
.sprite({fps: 1, no_of_frames: 16, rewind: true })

});

$(window).scroll(function() {   
clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
 $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
 $('#bird').spStop()

}, 250));

});
$(window).scroll(function() {


$('#bird').spStart()

});
```

Comment: I don't see any animation in jsfiddle.  Your fiddle is suffering errors

Comment: Same here... don't see anything in either one...

Comment: You need to scroll up and down in the result area - it works in Chrome (albeit with the problem in the above question) . I Haven't tested in any other browser. Sorry for dodgy code - its taken many hours to get this far.

Comment: I just viewed both in Firefox also

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096429/can-i-declare-logic-on-jquery-for-the-start-and-end-of-a-scrolling-event

Comment: i understand that thats a solution but struggling to implement it

Comment: OK I managed to start it properly by scrolling - now just need to stop it and start again - by - stopping scrolling and scrolling again http://jsfiddle.net/fGmbe/98/

Comment: getting closer ....   http://jsfiddle.net/fGmbe/107/